# SOSL Doesn't find data with wildcards

Tags: apex, soql, query, sosl

I'm working on a query to find some duplicate records by name. I take the name and replace anything thats not a letter with a wildcard. I wind up with a query that looks like this:

```
FIND {Name*Name*} IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING ACCOUNT (Id, Name)
```

I've got a few duplicate records in the sandbox:

```
Account(Name = 'Name4Name')
Account(Name = 'Name four Name')
Account(Name = 'Name4Name Name')
```

However, only "Name4Name" & "Name4Name Name" is returned as a query result.

The documentation says:

> Use an asterisk (*) to find items that match zero or more characters at the middle or end of your query.
>
> Use a question mark (?) to find items that match only one character at the middle or end of your query.

From this, I would expect all names to be returned in the query, but only the first & last ones are returned. I'm a bit stumped here - how can I get all of these records to return? Why does only one value return in the first place?

---

Looks like this query runs fine:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%NAME%Name%'
```

Pretty weird that SOQL works fine where SOSL fails. Will post as answer later but would be interested in hearing why these two queries are different.

Comment: You mean SOSL and not SOQL, right?

Comment: Yes - thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like unexplainable bug. When there is exactly 1 word between 2 `name`s like `name someWord name someOtherWord`, it does not return the record. However, if you add spaces for wildcard characters, it seems to be fine:

```
FIND {Name * Name *} IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING ACCOUNT (Name)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thats a great catch! Surprised to see the version without spaces show up when the query has spaces.